# load dialog box before page loads

Tags: jquery, arrays, jsp

When I click on one of the links, a dialog box should open but previously shown data should not be removed from the page. Please find the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/ssLY3/50/

Please check the sample code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#content1").load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});

$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

When i click on Page3 link, dialog box should open with content on it and previously shown data when clicked on Home/Page1/Page2 should not be removed from the page, please suggest.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand the question. Can you try a step-by-step description of what you want to occur?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - When i click on Home.Page1/Page2 link, data should be displayed below as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/ssLY3/50/. but when i click on Page3 link, an dialog box should open with some data on it and previously shown data on page when clicked on Home/Page1/Page2 should be available behind, i'm trying to achieve functionality similar to About Internet Explorer in IE. Whenwe click tools->About Internet Explorer a new window is opened with some data on it, similarly i want to open a new dialog box with some data on it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put something on the 3rd "about" link so that you know to *not* process it. e.g. a class

```
<li><a href="page4.html" class="about">Page 3</a>
```

then the code becomes something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).is('.about')) {
            $("#dialog").dialog();
        } else {
            $("#content1").load($(this).attr('href'));
        }
    });
});
```